# How to copy column to another dataframe but allow duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes, let's say `df1` and `df2`. `df1` contains data about what team members participated in some competition in what attempts. `df2` contains data about how well did the team do in the attemps. I need to add a column to to `df1` which would copy the data from `df2.success` to every row according to the team, like this:

```
df1
  attempt team name   
0 1       A    Alice
1 1       A    Bob
2 1       B    Charlie
3 1       B    Daniel
4 2       A    Alice
5 2       A    Bob
6 2       B    Charlie
7 2       B    Eva
```

```
df2
  attempt team success
0 1       A    True
1 1       B    False
2 2       A    False
3 2       B    True
```

and the result should be

```
df1
  attempt team name    success   
0 1       A    Alice   True
1 1       A    Bob     True
2 1       B    Charlie False
3 1       B    Daniel  False
4 2       A    Alice   False
5 2       A    Bob     False
6 2       B    Charlie True
7 2       B    Eva     True
```

The problem is that the dataframes have a different number of rows so I need to duplicate some data and I keep getting bunch of errors when trying to do this with `loc`.

```
df1['success'] = df2.loc[(df1["attempt"].values, df1["team"].values), ["success"]]['success'].values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['attempt', 'team'], how='left')
```

Is that what you where looking for ?